# Twisted, MySQLdb and (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away') using Twisted adbapi

Tags: python, mysql, timeout, twisted, mysql-python

In twisted I am a perpetual event loop that is always lookig for a new query to run  It polls a SQS queue and are are times where time between queres is long enough to time out and this is the error I get when a new query arrives...

> MySQLdb _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has
>   gone away')

here is my connection

```
self.pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", self.parms['host'], self.parms['username'], self.parms['password'], self.parms['database'])
```

Here is the logic I use to try and solve the problem.

```
try:
    d = self.pool.runQuery(query, ())
except:
    self.pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", self.parms['host'], self.parms['username'], self.parms['password'], self.parms['database']) 
    d = self.pool.runQuery(query, ())
    print 'Reconnecting'
```

Problem is that it does not seem to work very well.  So..if a get a 206 error the try reconnection and execute the query again.  What is best practice to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience with **adbapi**, but **cp_reconnect** parameter, mentioned in [docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool.html#__init__),  looks promising.

Thus your pool initialization will look something like:

```
self.pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", self.parms['host'], self.parms['username'], self.parms['password'], self.parms['database'], cp_reconnect=True)
```

Comment: I think reconnect can hide a problem if something fails mid transaction.  So be careful.