# Twisted adbapi cp_reconnect not working

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

I have a cyclone web service that talks to a MySQL database. When there is no activity for a while (more than 8 hours I'm guessing), I get the following error unti I restart the web service:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

I've seen [this post regarding cp_reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656499/twisted-mysqldb-and-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away-using-twisted-adbapi), and I have implemented this when creating my connection pool:

```
pool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", host=self.host, user=self.user,
    passwd=self.password, db=self.database, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
    cp_reconnect=True)
```

I would have thought this would have fixed it, and it seemed to for a while, but now I'm seeing the "MySQL server has gone away" error again after there is no activity on the server for a while.

I have read [this MySQL documentation regarding wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout), and I could fix it that way I suppose, but why doesn't the cp_reconnect feature work for me? I am interpreting the adbapi docs to mean that if you specify the cp_reconnect parameter, that adbadpi will handle the error sent by MySQL and re-attempt the query for you. So basically you don't have to handle the error directly in your code. Am I misunderstanding that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some discussions on the twisted mailing list and looking through the twisted bug tracker, it turns out that this is a known bug that has not yet been fixed.

Here is a link to the [mailing list discussion](http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2012-October/026104.html).

Here is a link to the [twisted bug tracker issue](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/4964).

Possible solutions:

1. Increase the wait_timeout value on the server.
2. Override methods in the ConnectionPool class, [referenced above](http://www.gelens.org/2009/09/13/twisted-connectionpool-revisited/).
3. Setup a periodic "ping" in each connection to keep it alive.
4. Fix the bug in adbapi myself.

Of these, I'm probably going to go with #1.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for the solution for this a couple of years ago. The solution I found somewhere on the web and settled with was subclassing `ConnectionPool` and overriding `_runInteraction`, where you force reconnect on specific error codes.
A quick google search lead me to this website: http://www.gelens.org/2009/09/13/twisted-connectionpool-revisited/ with a code included.
I haven't had to think about dying MySQL connections ever again.

Comment: Before finding this solution I used a "hammer to finetune the microscope" - creating LoopingTask which would execute "SELECT TRUE" against the database every 5 minutes.

Comment: Keep in mind that `_runInteraction` is a private, unsupported API (notice the leading underscore), so you'll need to remember to carefully check with each new version of Twisted that this is still supported.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a discussion going on the twisted mailing list. I will report back with any findings/conclusions.

Comment: Curious if @user1334007 heard anything back however for the benefit of the public, above link is broken now but accessible via Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20101111172427/http://www.gelens.org/2009/09/13/twisted-connectionpool-revisited

Answer (score 2):

The link http://www.gelens.org/2009/09/13/twisted-connectionpool-revisited/ is not working anymore, not even the Web Archive version. Here an excerpt from Twistar 1.3 that makes a reference to the same solution:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twistar

```
class ReconnectingMySQLConnectionPool(adbapi.ConnectionPool):
    """
    This connection pool will reconnect if the server goes away.  This idea was taken from:
    http://www.gelens.org/2009/09/13/twisted-connectionpool-revisited/
    """
    def _runInteraction(self, interaction, *args, **kw):
        try:
            return adbapi.ConnectionPool._runInteraction(self, interaction, *args, **kw)
        except MySQLdb.OperationalError, e:
            if e[0] not in (2006, 2013):
                raise
            log.err("Lost connection to MySQL, retrying operation.  If no errors follow, retry was successful.")
            conn = self.connections.get(self.threadID())
            self.disconnect(conn)
            return adbapi.ConnectionPool._runInteraction(self, interaction, *args, **kw)
```